# Saving videos using cv2 in windows and playing them

Tags: python

I am using lepton 3.5 with purethermal mini board to get thermal videos. I am using the below code to get the videos but when I try to play the saved videos none of the video players are able to play it.
I am using windows 10 and python 3.9 with opencv.

```
from import_clr import *
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate_videoclips
clr.AddReference("ManagedIR16Filters")
clr.AddReference("TIFFfile")
clr.AddReference("LeptonUVC")
from flirpy.camera.lepton import Lepton
import cv2
from Lepton import CCI
from IR16Filters import IR16Capture, NewIR16FrameEvent, NewBytesFrameEvent
from System.Drawing import ImageConverter
from System import Array, Byte
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy
import time
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib
found_device = None
for device in CCI.GetDevices():
    if device.Name.startswith("PureThermal"):
            found_device = device
            break
    if not found_device:
        print("Couldn't find lepton device")
    else:
        lep = found_device.Open()
    # lep, = (dev.Open()
    # for dev in CCI.GetDevices())
    print(lep.sys.GetCameraUpTime())
cv2_cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
cv2_cap.set(3, 160)
cv2_cap.set(4, 120)
cv2.namedWindow("lepton", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
print ("Running, ESC or Ctrl-c to exit...")
while True:
            ret, img = cv2_cap.read()
            fshape = img.shape
            fheight = fshape[0]
            fwidth = fshape[1]
            print(fwidth, fheight)
            if ret == False:
                print ("Error reading image")
                break
            cv2.imshow("lepton", cv2.resize(img, (640, 480)))
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('outputvideo.avi', fourcc, 9.0,(160, 120))
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

also, I get the below warning

[ WARN:0] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-9fdcu927\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (682) CvCapture_MSMF::initStream Failed to set mediaType (stream 0,
(160x122 @ 9) MFVideoFormat_RGB24(unsupported media type)
[ WARN:1] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-9fdcu927\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (434) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB termina
ting async callback

Comment: `none of the video players are able to play it` – can you share any of that videos?

Comment: How can I share it?

Comment: Google.Drive for example

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_fAS3MTMxqKVruOfWsuFdYEIrazxxRWH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi were you able to see the video?

Comment: Yes, but I have no idea why it's not playing. Sorry